# Change icon for an application from the command line?

Tags: command-line, x11, window-manager, icons

Is there a way to change the icon of an application's window from the command line?

For instance, I'd like to have separate icons for Firefox windows under different profiles (different processes), change the icon of the terminal if it runs `tmux`, etc.

By 'icon' I mean the small picture shown by window switcher, typically invoked with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. In particular, I'm interested for this to work under `xfwm4`, but a more general solution would only be welcome.

Apparently, neither `xdotool` nor `wmctrl` are capable of this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am also only able to change for some windows. E.g. kitty terminal works, but not xfce4-terminal. Beside xseticon I have also tried this https://benizi.com/set-icon/ and the like (but no luck). `xprop` show the new icon, but not in e.g Alt+Tab

Answer (score 11):

[xseticon](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/xseticon/) allows you to do exactly that.

Comment: The release of xseticon at the link in this post no longer works on Ubuntu 22.04, but [this fork](https://github.com/jmfernandez/xseticon) does.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `xprop` and click on a window, you see that the icon is among the "metadata" assigned to the window structure in your X server, under name and type `_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL)`. These parameters can be changed by other X applications, for instance, window managers write and change a whole bunch of stuff in there. The key function will be `XChangeProperty`.

I'm not aware of any tools that do this easily from commandline but this doesn't mean they don't exist.

In any case, it could be written from scratch, it's not hard (even though writing in raw `xlib` will make your chest hair stand on end and probably give you PTSD).

Comment: I have tried `xseticon` as recommended by @dakatine. It uses `_NET_WM_ICON`, and has changed the icon, in the top left corner (in the title bar). However there is no change in the task-bar, or system tray (when an app has an icon here). Do you know why the task-bar is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

It could be different for different OSes / flavours. Mostly by editing the desktop file directly at /usr/share/applications or by copying or creating the desktop file at /home/username/.local/share/applications/ , this could be achieved.

Icon=/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/apps/firefox.png

Please refer http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html

Comment: Yhank you, I know that. I need to change the icon of a window dynamically; I suppose it's somehow standard under X11.