# Change terminal emulator icon based on running program

Tags: cinnamon, gui, gnome-terminal

I have started using more "ncurses" style applications, like `vim` and `ipython` that run directly from the terminal emulator. As a result, I frequently have multiple terminal applications open, but the problem is that each one has the same icon, so when I try to Alt+Tab between windows to pull up the one I want, all terminal applications look the same. For the moment I've been using `gvim` rather than `vim` specifically for this reason, as you can see it shows up nicely with its own icon:

[image: Alt tab view with two terminals, Firefox and gvim]

This seems like overkill. Ideally, running `vim` or `nvim` or `ipython` or `gdb` or some other long-running program that runs in the terminal would change the terminal icon to match some icon specified for the application.

I am using Cinnamon on Arch Linux. I'm OK with switching away from using GNOME terminal if there's a similar terminal emulator that has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Success! [Thanks google and SO for directing me to `xseticon`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222267/322773).

First [install xseticon](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/xseticon/)

Add this script somewhere in your `PATH`:

```sh
# setWinIcon.sh
#!/bin/sh                                                                                           

# Usage: setWinIcon [title] [icon]                                                                  
# - title: a string to match within the title of the window                                         
# - icon: path to the icon file. Use png for best results.                                          

title="$1"                                                                                          
ICONPATH="$2"                                                                                       

known_windows=$(wmctrl -l |grep $title|awk '{ print $1 }')                                          

for id in ${known_windows}                                                                          
do                                                                                                  
    xseticon -id "$id" "$ICONPATH"                                                                  
done
```

Then add this function in your `.vimrc`, replacing path as required:

```sh
system("setWinIcon.sh", "$WINDOWID [path/to/vimicon.png]")
```

Note that this will not revert the icon. You could trigger a `vimLeave` autocmd to refresh it to the icon of your terminal like this:

```sh
au vimLeave system("setWinIcon.sh", "$WINDOWID [path/to/termicon.png]")
```

For the other programs, just configure them as an alias like `alias ipython="setWinIcon.sh $WINDOWID [path/to/ipyicon.png] && ipython && setWinIcon.sh $WINDOWID [path/to/termicon.png]"`