# Selecting a custom icon for particular Xfce terminal windows

Tags: debian, xfce4-terminal

I am running Debian,and want to utilize the multiple workspaces feature as a means of managing the large amount of terminal windows I tend to have open, but in order for the individual workspaces to be visually distinguishable, the icons of what is open in them must be, which is my issue here.

So basically I am asking is it possible to change the icon for individual XFce terminal windows?

Comment: the icons of applications open in each workspace determine the icon for the workspace, when they are all filled with terminal windows, but I have categorized the workspaces by purpose, they still all have the same icon and are indistinguishable visually on the desktop, kind of defeating the purpose of having multiple workspaces in general

Comment: ok give me  a bit I will take some screen shots and appropriately humiliate myself with child like creations using the Debian equivalent of microsoft paint

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179174

Comment: great yes well I will try xseticon now and see how I go, other than that I've found a lot more resources on window management and customization for the gnome terminal, so if that's what I need to do i will just have to switch terminal display applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch `xfce4-terminal` with customised icon, title, geometry and so on. For example,

```
xfce4-terminal --icon=/home/user/scripts/green.png --title="Custom title" --geometry=100x30+130+200
```

The above command would open a terminal window with specified icon and title, 100x30 characters in size, positioned 130 pixels from screen left and 200 pixels from screen top.

You could then create a bunch of scripted aliases for such commands, e.g. rterm, gterm, bterm, for variants with red, green, and blue icons, and so on.

I find colours better than any other way of distinguishing things.

Getting your terminals onto the desired workspace can be achieved with `wmctrl -s`. When scripting these, I'd add e.g. a 50ms pause to allow the window to reliably appear, and then issue the `wmctrl` instruction to push the session to whichever workspace you need. Perhaps have variants like rterm1, rterm2, gterm1, and so on.

Comment: thanks so what is the file path for the image file for the default xforce terminal window icon?

Comment: @Adam The real icon is an svg file, but luckily there are png duplicates. Try `locate -A -i xfce4 term png`. I get the following results:

`/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/panel/16/xfce4-terminal.png`

`/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-dark/panel/16/xfce4-terminal.png`

`/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-focal-universe/64x64/xfce4-terminal_utilities-terminal.png`

The default icon on my system looks like this though:

`/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/128/Terminal.png`

(along with other sizes, if they produce clearer rendering). Sorry re. formatting here; it ignores newlines.